# How best to manage an array of optionals in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, option-type

I'm looking to manage an array of optionals and to achieve the following behavior:

Initialize with nil to some constant size (going to use generic type T for brevity):

```
var myRay = [T?](repeating: nil, count: 5)
```

So we have: [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

I want a function to add items to this array from the beginning, replacing the nil values as it goes. After the array is filled up with non-nil values, the function would just add the value on to the end of the array.

So if we called this function 7 times on the array above, it would look like this:

```
insert(item: T, array: inout [T]?)

x1: [X, nil, nil, nil, nil]
x2: [X, X, nil, nil, nil]
x3: [X, X, X, nil, nil]
x4: [X, X, X, X, nil]
x5: [X, X, X, X, X]
x6: [X, X, X, X, X, X]
x7: [X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
```

*(Where X is a non-nil value)*

I've come up with the following solution which **does work**. I'm throwing this out there because I think there may very well be a much better solution, and I think it's a pretty interesting problem that crops up in languages like swift that have optionals. Posting my Solution below:

```
private func insertValue<T>(element: T, array: inout [T?]) {
    let insertIndex = getFirstNilIndex(fromArray: array)
    array.insert(element, at: insertIndex)

    if let lastElement = array.last, let _ = lastElement {
        // the last element is a non-nil value of type T
    } else {
        // the last element is nil
        array.remove(at: array.endIndex - 1)
    }
}

// returns index of first nil object in array, or the end index if the array does not contain any nil values
private func getFirstNilIndex<T>(fromArray array: [T?]) -> Int {
    for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
        if item == nil {
            return index
        }
    }
    return array.endIndex
}
```

This works due to a kind of weird circumstance where we have a doubly wrapped optional. Array.last returns an optional, and when the non-nil value that it returns is itself an optional, you have to unwrap the value all over again! I didn't think this would work, because I didn't know if Swift would differentiate between .some(.none) and .none.

So my question to all you folks is can you see a better or more 'swifty' way to accomplish this? What do you think of this solution? Can you recommend a different approach, or do you simply have any informative comments on this aspect of the language that would help me understand this process more clearly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The existing `index(where:)` method can be used to find the index of the first `nil` entry.
- Then *replace* the entry if a `nil` element was found, otherwise
  append an entry.

That is more simple than to always insert a new entry and then to check
if the last element should be removed.

```
func insertValue<T>(element: T, array: inout [T?]) {

    if let idx = array.index(where: { $0 == nil } ) {
        array[idx] = element
    } else {
        array.append(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even make that a binary search.

Comment: @zneak: Yes, but if you find *some* nil entry with a binary search then you would still have to find the *first* nil entry.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to compare pairs instead of single elements, checking if N is nil but N-1 isn't.